# How do I know which is the fastest processor which is supported by a specific chipset?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, chipset

I have an old laptop, I want to upgrade my cpu or motherboard, but don't know the knowledge of computer hardware .I have added a 4g memory and cleaned my fan. Can I upgrade a laptop Mobile Intel® HM55 Express Chipset Intel core i5 430M to a Intel corei7 3612QM CPU ? 
thank you in advance!

Comment: Base it on power requirements and the socket.  The example you used are two different sockets.  Furthermore your motherboard can't be upgraded

Comment: Aha , I know it now. thank you ! Tis base on TDP and socket(my socket is Socket 989 rPGA ; http://valid.canardpc.com/e553em ). I find that Intel core i7 640M should be the fastest processor which is supported by my chipset. But I think this i7 cpu would be just a little better than mine. So I think the better thing I should do is to bud a new laptop... @Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

The Intel core i5 430M in your laptop cannot be upgraded, because it is directly soldered to your motherboard.  It is not designed to be user-replaceable or user-upgradeable.  There are some Intel-based laptops with replaceable processors, but unfortunately for you, you do not have one.

Additionally, laptop motherboards are also not user-replaceable or user-upgradeable, due to size constraints of the different cases, amongst other things.  With desktops, you can easily move a motherboard from one case to another, but with laptops this just isn't so.

Comment: thanks. But the dell I1564D-158B(laptop)? service manual say that one can take off the processor. I think if I upgrade my motherboard , then  I should have a better fan system to make the cpu cool down , right ?

Comment: You can't upgrade your motherboard though

Comment: Well, I was going off your statement that you have a Intel core i5 430M.  According to [this link](http://ark.intel.com/products/43537/Intel-Core-i5-430M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_26-GHz), you've got a 50/50 that your chip is soldered to the board (BGA) vs removable (rPGA).  If the manual for your laptop says it's removable, then you're in luck.  However, if you do plan to upgrade your processor, you must make sure it has a thermal limit that is equal to or less than your current processor, or you'll overheat.  Additionally, ensure your laptop has BIOS support for the upgraded processor.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_i5_Mobile/i5-430M_%28PGA988%29.html) for upgrade options that would work, provided your laptop's BIOS supports them.  Looks like you can go as high as an Intel Core i7-640M.